# Choice of penalty term when the constraint optimization problem have multiple constraints?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

For the following minimization problem:

\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min }&{f\left( x \right)}\\
{}&{s\left( x \right) \le 0}\\
{}&{r\left( x \right) = 0}
\end{array}

A common way to turn this into unconstraint optimization problem is to penalize it using the penalty $p$ as:

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min }&{f\left( x \right) + p{{\left[ {r\left( x \right)} \right]}^2}}
\end{array} + p{\left[ {\max \left( {s\left( x \right),0} \right)} \right]^2}$

My question is that:

If I have $m$ constraint ${s_1}\left( x \right),{s_2}\left( x \right),...,{s_m}\left( x \right)$ and $n$ constraint ${r_1}\left( x \right),{r_2}\left( x \right),...,{r_n}\left( x \right)$, is it possible to use just one penalization constant $p$ for penalizing all of them ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?$$\min f(x) + p\left( \sum_{i=1}^nr_i^2(x) \right)+p\left( \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\max \{s_i (x),0\}\right)^2 \right)$$

Comment: wow that look so nit ! But is it safe to do so ? I am an engineer so I dont have alot of mathematic knowledge

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh Yes, it's safe. The method is even described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method#Description)